# Parsing names with pyparsing

Tags: python, pyparsing

I have a file of names and ages,

```
john 25 
bob 30 
john bob 35
```

Here is what I have so far

```
from pyparsing import *

data = '''
    john 25 
    bob 30 
    john bob 35
'''

name = Word(alphas + Optional(' ') + alphas)

rowData = Group(name +
                Suppress(White(" ")) +
                Word(nums))

table = ZeroOrMore(rowData)

print table.parseString(data)
```

the output I am expecting is

`[['john', 25], ['bob', 30], ['john bob', 35]]`

Here is the stacktrace

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\mccauley\Desktop\client.py", line 11, in <module>
    eventType = Word(alphas + Optional(' ') + alphas)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1657, in __init__
    self.name = _ustr(self)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 122, in _ustr
    return str(obj)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1743, in __str__
    self.strRepr = "W:(%s)" % charsAsStr(self.initCharsOrig)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyparsing.py", line 1735, in charsAsStr
    if len(s)>4:
TypeError: object of type 'And' has no len()
```

Comment: I take it that you're deliberately choosing `pyparsing` as a learning exercise? Using built-in string functions or even a regex would be better for something so trivial

Comment: @JonClements actually this is part of a much large project, for which I believe pyparsing is much more suited than regex, I really just need to know how to do the single space thing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pyparsing` automatically gets rid of whitespace so that you can write cleaner grammars. So, your name parser should be something more like:

```
# Parse for a name with an optional surname
# Note that pyparsing is built to accept "john doe" or "john        doe"
name = Word(alphas) + Optional(Word(alphas))
```

And then, the row parser:

```
# Parses a row of a name and an age
row = Group(name) + Word(nums)
```

You'll get a rather complicated structure, though, `([(['john', 'doe'], {}), '25'], {})` for each row, but I hope you can see how to work with this. I'd recommend not really using pyparsing to parse the whole string, but parse it line-by-line iteratively, if your data is line based. Makes stuff simpler, I think:

```
for line in input_string.splitlines():
    results = row.parseString(line)
    # Do something with results...
```

Comment: The structure only looks complicated when you print it out. In fact, the structure is a ParseResults that can be iterated over just like a nested list, or accessed by key like a dict if any of the elements have been given results names. Since you have `Group`ed the leading name (nicely done, btw), you can even do tuple unpacking like `name,age = results`. If you change row to `row = Group(name)('name') + Word(nums)('age')` then you get to access the results by name using `results.age` or `results['age']`, which really helps when you also have optional elements in your expression.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire Also if I'm not mistaken (correct me if I'm wrong!), there is `.scanString` to handle the `for line in input_string.splitlines():` problem. That is, it creates an iterator that yields the output of a single pass of the grammar. Thus you can replace it with something like `for results in row.scanString():`.

Comment: Close - `scanString` returns a generator that yields a `(tokens, start, end)` tuple for each match found. `searchString` is just a thin wrapper around `scanString`, `[tokens for tokens,start,end in expr.scanString(s)]`.

Answer (score 0):

The following code may solve your problem using built in string library.

```
def main():
    f = open('filename.txt')
    fe = open('ERROR.TXT','w+')
    for line in f.readlines():
        # print line,
        lst = line.split()
        try:
            name = lst[0]
            age = lst[1]

        # process name and age valuse

        except IndexError as e:
            print e
            fe.write(e)
        except IOError as e:
            print e
            fe.write(e)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     main()
```

Comment: I wish. Please see my comment on the question.